# When using the Airflow ShortCircuitOperator, I'm getting invalid arguments passed where ignore_downstream_trigger_rules. Why?

Tags: airflow

Let's say I have this ShortCircuitOperator as

```
    is_xpa_running = ShortCircuitOperator(
    dag=dag,
    task_id="is_switch_on",
    python_callable=_is_switch_on,
    ignore_downstream_trigger_rules=False,
    op_kwargs=configs,
    provide_context=True
)
```

It raises this error:

> airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Invalid arguments were passed to >ShortCircuitOperator (task_id: is_switch_running). Invalid arguments were:
> **kwargs: {'ignore_downstream_trigger_rules': False}

Why?

Comment: what is the value of configs (in op_kwargs=configs) ? also add the definition of _is_switch_on please.

Comment: configs is just a dictionary of key-value pairs and definition of _is_switch_on is

def _is_xpa_running(**kwargs):

    return bool(kwargs["switch"])

Comment: which version of airflow are you using ? the error you means no "ignore_downstream_trigger_rules" attribute in ShortCircuitOperator. I think it is exist from 2.3.0 only

Comment: Oh I see. I'm using apache-airflow 2.2.5. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the Airflow 2.2.5 source code https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.2.5/_modules/airflow/operators/python.html#ShortCircuitOperator.execute, there is no support for ignore_downstream_trigger_rules.

Starting 2.3.0, you have the support for it https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.3.0/_api/airflow/operators/python/index.html#airflow.operators.python.ShortCircuitOperator